# Where DateTimeFormat.MonthName[12] is used?

Tags: .net

According to MSDN in .Net DateTimeFormat.MonthName should contain exactly 13 elements with 12 element should be empty string. What this empty string is used for?

Comment: Actually the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx) stats "In a 12-month calendar, the 13th element of the array is an empty string." – no mention that the last element is *always* an empty string and the text even reduces it to calendars that do *not* have 12 months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For index 12. Indexes 0--11 are the actual months in, for example, the `en-US` culture (January, February, etc.). The issue is that some `Calendar`s have thirteen months.

Comment: So is there a value indicating how much month there is in calendar?

Comment: Use `Calendar.GetMonthsInYear`. It's dependent on the year because in some cultures (e.g., `he-IL`) the number of months varies from year to year). For a specific example, see year 5763 in the Hebrew calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Because in some cultures year consists of 13 months.